# Is there implicit limit for DNN input size of OpenCV Android?

Tags: android, opencv, caffe, forward

I trained a Caffe model which does NOT specify input sizes. Then I ran it on Android using OpenCV. The code is like below.

```
private void runEntireImageTest(Mat inY) {
    float scaleFactor = 1.0f / 255.0f;
    Scalar mean = new Scalar(0);
    Mat resized = new Mat();

    // (550, 441) runs OK. (smaller sized runs also fine)
    // (551, 441), (550, 442) crash.
    // (441, 550) crashes

    Imgproc.resize(inY, resized, new Size(550, 441));
    Mat segBlob = Dnn.blobFromImage(resized, scaleFactor, resized.size(), mean, false, false);
    mNet.setInput(segBlob);

    // if input size is above some value, crash will happen here
    Mat lastLayer = mNet.forward();
    Mat outY = lastLayer.reshape(1, 1);
}
```

As it is written in the comment, there seems to be some *intrinsic*, or *implicit* limitation for the input size. `(550, 441)` ran okay, but `(551, 441)` will cause `SIGSEGV`:

`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6d494bd744 in tid 19693 (myappname), pid 19661 (myappname)`

I think it's not a memory problem because `(550, 441)` runs fine but `(441, 550)` will crash. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?